# Which one is best open source GIS software where we can use Google/bing/yahoo maps as a basemap?

Tags: digitizing

Which one is best open source GIS software where we can use  Google/bing/yahoo maps as a basemap? i want to update my shp files using any of these basemap.

Comment: Have you looked at Qgis?

Answer (score 3):

Since it seems like you want to edit Shapefiles, I would recommend using a desktop GIS. Have a look at QGIS which provides the basemaps you are looking for through the OpenLayers plugin.

Answer (score 0):

OpenLayers I think, but you will need to work with geoserver or mapserver, though. QGis would be a much more complete/easy application in any case.

Hope this helps,